# What's the difference between Disjunctive Normal Form and FULLY Disjunctive Normal Form?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

Could somebody please explain that the difference is between Disjunctive Normal Form and Fully Disjunctive Normal form. Is disjunctive normal form just minterms and fully disjunctive normal form the canonical form of that expression?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunctive_normal_form#Definition

Comment: How would you convert from disjunctive normal form to fully disjunctive normal form?

Answer (score 1):

To convert to the full version, replace each "p and p" with "p"
after changing conjunctions like "p and q and p" to "p and p and q".
This newfangled distinction is unnecessary.
Us old timers handled logical normal forms without it.